# RabbitMQ shared by live and staging installs using Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, rabbit-mq

Is it possible/recommended for 2 separate installs of M2 to share the same RabbitMQ install? Is there a way to separate their data like with Elastic Search where you define a separate prefix?

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way is to install multiple instances of RabbitMQ on different ports on the same machine, I think this resource might help https://lazareski.com/multiple-rabbitmq-instances-on-1-machine/.

Cheers and good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why the suggestion to create another virtual host in rabbitmq was downvoted, because it must be the easiest way to achieve what was requested.

Sure, running multiple rabbitmq instances on a single server makes them completely separated, but when it comes to management - for me it's easier to handle single rabbitmq instance, also it would use less system resources.

Answer (score 0):

You can create separate [virtual host](https://www.rabbitmq.com/vhosts.html)  and configure it in [Magento configuration](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/prereq/install-rabbitmq.html) (see virtualhost)